# ZKemkeeper ReadGeneralLogData function returns false

Tags: zkteco, zkemkeeper

I'm try to get the log data from a SpeedFace v5l.
When I call the

```
ReadGeneralLogData(machineNumber);
```

I get false.

If I call the

```
ReadAllUserID(machineNumber);
```

I get true.
Any idea why this could be?

When I check the last error. I got 0 ERR_NO_DATA, but we have events on the device

Answer (score 0):

Newly launched ZkTeco devices are not compatible with their SDKs. You have to relay on their web application as officially no SDKs are launched for new devices. Some of the operations given in the SDK will make the SpeedFace V5L to display the "Authendication Failure" randomly. Once this error comes, you have to flash the device, no other option.

So, don't try with ZK's old/new SDKs with new devices with temperature and mask detections. If you need web API, you can try with CAMS (http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html), Zk's API Partner.

Answer (score 0):

Choice the Time Attendance Terminal will make the device working with UTimeMaster, BioTime 8.0, TA Push SDK, Attendance Management software or offline SDK.

Choice the Access Control Terminal will make device working with ZKBioAccess software or AI AC Push SDK.

For that go to "System" -> "Device Type Setting" -> and choice the "Time Attendance Terminal"

But this attendance, the access control is best to be modified at the beginning. If the customer is uploaded, it is easy to modify it easily, because the user data and record are all deleted because of the modification.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to write your own ADMSServer.
So if you would like to write your own program and interact with the camera. I would contact ZKTeco Europe and ask for documentation.

With a query command the camera will then push the attendance records to your endpoint.